# Create graph in tooltip of highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Have some data to display as column in highchart. The data is about registrations per month in columns.

Following is the link for jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/CkkbF/161/
In each tooltip of graph want to show another column chart.

```
$(function () {
    // Registrations Data
    var data ={10:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":3,"Night":5},//Jan
        12:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":5,"Night":5},//Feb
        15:{"Morning":5,"Afternoon":3,"Night":7},//Mar
        17:{"Morning":8,"Afternoon":3,"Night":6},//Apr
        18:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":3,"Night":13}, //May
        22:{"Morning":12,"Afternoon":3,"Night":7},//June
        15:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":8,"Night":5},//July
        27:{"Morning":12,"Afternoon":11,"Night":4},//Aug
        17:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":5,"Night":10},//Sep
        10:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":3,"Night":5},//Oct
        14:{"Morning":2,"Afternoon":4,"Night":8},Nov
        24:{"Morning":12,"Afternoon":7,"Night":5},DEc
    }
    var series_data=[]

    for (key in data) {series_data.push(parseInt(key))}

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },

        series: [{
            data: series_data   
        }]
    });
});
```

E.g. In above jsfiddle example
So on hover of Column associated with January data , it should show another column highchart in tooltip {"Morning":2,"Afternoon":3,"Night":5}.
i.e. In morning 2, Afternoon 3 and Night 5 registrations.

Any help how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

To make a tooltip of a point contain another chart you need to do 3 things (I am sure there are other ways but this is the basic method). I do not remember where I pulled this from as it is not my code but it works:

1 First set up data to use for each point.

```
var data0 = [12, 12];
var data1 = [6, 12];
var toolTipData = [];
toolTipData.push(data0);
toolTipData.push(data1);
```

2 Then build a method to pull the appropriate data points out.

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var i = this.key;
                setTimeout( function() {
                    $("#hc-tooltip").highcharts({
                        series: [{
                            data: toolTipData[i]
                        }]
                    });
                }, 10)
            }
        },
```

3 Now you need to put the chart you just made into a container.

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var i = this.key;
                setTimeout( function() {
                    $("#hc-tooltip").highcharts({
                        series: [{
                            data: toolTipData[i]
                        }]
                    });
                }, 10)

                return '<div id="hc-tooltip"></div>';
            }
        },
```

The `setTimeout` is used to smooth out the creation of the tooltip/chart. So, what we are doing here is creating an array (`toolTipData`) and populating it with the data (`data0` and `data1`) that will be used for each point's tooltip chart. We access the `toolTipData` via the *index* of the point we are showing the tooltip for.

Comment: This pretty much works. However, when the tooltip hides itself (i.e. cursor leaves the point), the tooltip's chart sticks around. I added a mouseOut handler to destroy the chart, but the chart it still visible for a few moments after the tooltip disappears. Any way to hide fade it out nicely with the tooltip?

Comment: Without seeing your specific code I cannot say. What version of highcharts are you using?

Comment: Fiddle with a rough representation here: https://jsfiddle.net/xnqop3u7/3/

Comment: Though I'm on 4.0.3, it behaves the same with the current version (6.0.x).

Comment: That is the tooltip `hideDelay` that you are seeing. It defaults to half a second (500). Try shortening it to around 250 or if you are feeling aggressive try 100.

Comment: Playing with the timeout helped, as did building separate tooltip charts (in divs with different IDs, i.e. `hc-tooltip-1` and `hc-tooltip-2`) for each of the two outer chart categories that required the tooltips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about having a chart inside the tooltip, but you can use HTML such as the following example from the API docs:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/footerformat/

```
tooltip: {
   shared: true,
   useHTML: true,
   headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
   pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
   '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} EUR</b></td></tr>',
   footerFormat: '</table>',
   valueDecimals: 2
}
```

No 100% sure how you would pass the data into it though...

Comment: In format it won't be possible - it requires pattern (string), while you need to call function (js) to create chart.